# Why isn't this jquery window working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to just get this to run: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/ (*Example 2 Specifically*)

My code:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Example of Windows</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="window.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $.window({
   showModal: true,
   modalOpacity: 0.5,
   icon: "http://www.fstoke.me/favicon.ico",
   title: "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers",
   content: $("#window_block2").html(), // load window_block2 html content
   footerContent: "<img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="img/star.png"> This is a nice plugin :^)";
});
    </script>


    <div id="example2" class='example_block'> 
            <h3>Demo</h3> 
            <div class='demo'> 
                <div id='window_block2' style='display:none;'> 
                    <div style='padding:10px;'> 
                        <div style='font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:10px; color:#44aaff;'>Introduction</div> 
                        <img style='border:0; float:left; margin:10px;' src='http://lh5.ggpht.com/_W-5oCUN3-sQ/TNUfmAY_mFI/AAAAAAAADwc/Dav33v1iBlY/s144/Professional%20JavaScript%20for%20Web%20Developers.jpg'/> 
                        <div> 
                            If you want to achieve JavaScript's full potential, it is critical to understand its nature, history, and limitations. 
                            This book sets the stage by covering JavaScript from its very beginning to the present-day incarnations that include 
                            support for the DOM and Ajax. It also shows you how to extend this powerful language to meet specific needs and create
                            seamless client-server communication without intermediaries such as Java or hidden frames.
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                <input type='button' value='Click Here to Create Window' onclick='createWindowWithHtml();'/> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </body>

</html>
```

Error: When I click the button, it does nothing! Anyone see any problems here? I feel like it might have to do with the embedded script.

Page now loads... just looks like this as if its firing the event when you onload, instead of when you click the buttton is something out of order here?
[image: img]

Anyone?!

Comment: Where's the function createWindowWithHtml()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that text is exactly how you have then you probably can't do this ...

```
"<img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="img/star.png"> This is a nice plugin :^)";
```

you more than likely need this ...

```
footerContent: "<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='img/star.png'> This is a nice plugin :^)"
```

you don't need the semi-colon at the end...or shouldn't at least

EDIT:

```
function createWindowWithHtml() {
    $.window({
        showModal: true,
        modalOpacity: 0.5,
        icon: "http://www.fstoke.me/favicon.ico",
        title: "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers",
        content: $("#window_block2").html(), // load window_block2 html content
        footerContent: "<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='img/star.png'> This is a nice plugin :^)"
    });
}
```

Comment: bdparrish - please see the error I am recieving now. This fixed that problem, but created another. What do you think? Please help.

Comment: showModal should be false?  in the normal .dialog() for jQuery the default behavior is to show the modal when you assign it as autoOpen.  my guess is that if you set showModal to false, and do some sort of call to showModal = true when you click the button. -- (you'll have to look at the documentation because I don't know what plugin you are using)

Comment: Bdparrish - please see the link that is at the top of the post it is the "Window" plugin for jquery

Comment: ok got it.  easy now.  you need to wrap the $.window() in a function called createWindowWithHtml(); --- see edit above.

Comment: @Rodolfo was spot on.  He submitted the right question.  You gotta be smarter than the code you are referencing so you know how to put it all together.